# Stuck with "Assist the people of Haafingar (5/5)" in my Journal

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I forgot to do the "Return of the Wolf Queen" quest before I bought a house and became the thane of solitude. So, even though "Assist the people of Haafingar (5/5)" has been completed, it annoyingly shows up in the Journal under misc. quests (I'm guessing that's the reason for this bug). What is the console command to remove this? Please help because a soiled journal irks me like a thorn :)

Comment: Sorry, I found the answer here: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thane_of_Haafingar#Bugs - I should have looked more thoroughly, hope this helps someone else...

Comment: You can post the answer yourself and accept it. There's nothing wrong with solving your own problems and leaving the information for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just complete another assistance quest in Solitude, it should update and then the quest will disappear from your journal.

The [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thane_of_Haafingar#Bugs) fix you mentioned in the comments by using the console may work for you, but it did not work for me so I had to do it the other way.

Comment: May be that someone updated the wiki within the last hour but it does mention either do the console command or simply complete another quest as you mention here.

Answer (score 0):

Hah! - as well as completing a further quest in Haafingar, at least in my play through, when I completed the Morthal Thaneship (is that a word, Thaneship?) the Haafingar one cleared from my Misc Quest list at the same time as the Morthal one did. Really amazing scripting there - LOL :-)

Comment: "thanedom", I should think

Answer (score 0):

I had this one stuck in my journal too on Skyrim Special Edition.  Thankfully it resolved immediately after installing the Unofficial SE Patch.  I had a few other bugged quests that did *not* get resolved, but this one did.